# Java: How to check if MySQL is installed or not on Windows?

Tags: java, mysql

I am developing a Java desktop application that will use `MySQL` DB on same host. How can I check if MySQL is installed or not on that host as soon as I launch my application?

I can surely check that `DriverManager#getConnection()` doesn't throws exception, but it doesn't tell whether `MySQL` is installed or not. `DriverManager#getConnection()` can throw exception in scenarios where URL is not correct (including incorrect port number), or user/password does't match, etc.

Comment: Why do you need to know exactly?  If you can't connect, does it make a difference?

Comment: @SteveSmith, I would like to inform user that they need to install MySQL first before using the product (as a prerequisite).

Comment: Fair enough.  My solution would be to show the message "Cannot connect to MySQL - Are you sure it's installed?" :)

Answer (score 2):

I do that by checking the if service installed or not.

worked for me even if the service isn't running.

```
private static boolean mysqlServiceExists() throws IOException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sc query");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.trim().startsWith("SERVICE_NAME: mysql")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Instate of `if (line.trim().startsWith("SERVICE_NAME: mysql"))` I used 
`if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("SERVICE_NAME: MYSQL"))` works perfectly

Comment: Windoze-only. Use the JDBC connection to connect for any platform.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily part of the installation procedure for a desktop application includes the writing of connection strings for any required DBMS operations.

These connection strings include the DBMS hostname, the credentials (username / password) and possibly the database name. If secure communication (TLS / SSL) is required, they mention that.

To solve the problem in your question, you create a default connection string in your software package. During the process of installing and/or starting your desktop app, you try to connect using it.  If your connection succeeds, good.

Such a connection string might be

```
     jdbc:mysql://localhost/nimish?user=defaultuser&password=secretsecret
```

That connects to a database on the user's machine called "nimish" with credentials defaultuser/secretsecret.

If your connection fails, you can usually tell from the error message what was wrong. Was the connection request rejected immediately? If so, the MySQL server is either not installed or not running. Did the server response time out? In that case the MySQL server has something wrong with it.  Did you get credential rejection (bad password, etc)? If so, you know that's the problem.

In those cases, your application pops open a dialog box saying, in a way that offers a suitably friendly user experience,

> Yo! User! This connection string didn't work. Wanna give me one that does?

Your dialog box can explain things like, "you have to make sure MySQL is running" if necessary. It can ask for a new password, and do whatever makes sense to your users.

This gives your application a way to work with a DBMS on another machine if that turns out to be useful. In that case your dialog box can say "your system administrator can give you this information."

You could write a separate, simple, troubleshooting app that will look around your user's file system trying to find MySQL and other prerequisite software, and announce such things as "MySQL doesn't seem to be running" when port 3306 doesn't respond. It can announce "I can't find the MySQL server software executable" But this is *hard* because things change over time in the way software is installed.

**Please note**: If you *know* your database will *always* be local, you should investigate using sqlite in place of MySQL. It doesn't need a server and so is easier to install and configure. Generally the point of using a DBMS like MySQL is to allow multiple users to share the same sets of data. So, you want flexibility in the configuration of connection strings.